# Что означает модель ветвления в гите a simple git branching model

Tags: git

Как она реализуется, какие преимущества этой модели ветвления?

Comment: [1 ссылка](https://gist.github.com/jbenet/ee6c9ac48068889b0912)

Comment: да никак она не «реализвуется». это используемый **пользователем** порядок действий. который прямо из документации к программе и следует. но всегда можно этот порядок усложнить и запутать — вот вам будет и «ваша новая персональная модель ветвления».